# To have div in view while scrolling window which is inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `"A"` div inside `"B"` div element when `"A"` div displays properties info which is small and div `"B"` large one .

B div doesnt have any vertical scroll .When I scroll window down vertically `"A"` div should be in view (i.e., follow scroll).When I move window scroll up , `"A"` div should move up .

`"A"` div should scroll up and down in `"B"` only .When I tried it floating on page and coming out of `"B"`.
When scroll page up "A" should be in view only `"B"` is in view .

Please help how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance

Edit1:

```
  <div id="graphView" class="tabcontent" style="display:block;">
                        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px; text-align: left;">
                            <div id="graphDiv" class="col-sm-9 graphViewStyle"> </div>
                            <div id="toolTipDiv" class="col-sm-3"  style="word-wrap: break-word; min-height:400px;max-height:400px;min-width:230px;overflow-y: auto;border:1px solid black;
                                 border-bottom-left-radius:4px;border-bottom-right-radius:4px;border-top-left-radius:4px;border-top-right-radius:4px;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

In pic , When I scroll window down , properties div should float and move down (should be in view) .But it should float only in parent div that is "graphview".

Here properties div is "tootTipDiv"

Comment: It would be usefull to post to base code to anderstand you
Otherwise , fix heights , and give "overflow:scroll" in your A's div's style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to my problem .

```
http://someweblog.com/hcsticky-jquery-floating-sticky-plugin/
```

Now the small div scrolls inside the parent div which i need .

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this ?

```
<div id="B style="height:500px">
    <div id="A" style="height:1000px;overflow-y:scroll">
         Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Or do you want your A div to move up and down B div  ? 
I didnt anderstand your question